# Rendering Markdown from Pagedown not in an editor

Tags: java, javascript, markdown, pagedown

I'm using [PageDown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) to allow my site's users to add comments, blog posts, etc. I'm using Java on the server side (Spring to be specific), and I can store the output of the PageDown editor in a database just fine.

Now I need to take that markdown and render it on the site as html, not in an editor, just as the comments and blog posts as they are being read.

I gather that the PageDown converter has a makeHtml() function that you can call on the client side via html. I've put together a little test:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>PageDown Test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PageDown/demo.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="PageDown/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PageDown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PageDown/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>PageDown Test</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(converter.makeHtml('${input}'));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The ${input} variable contains the markdown submitted by the user in a form. However, this breaks if the input is multiple lines, which will be most of the time.

My next option is to do this on the server side, but that seems hackish. My server is all Java, and since I can't find a PageDown.Sanitizer implemented in Java, I'll have to call the javascript library from Java, which seems gross.

I've tried googling for a standard way to render markdown to the client, but I keep just getting markdown editors, which I already have working. Is there a standard way to do this, either on the client side or on the server side (in Java)?

I don't really have any idea what I'm doing, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Have you asked the PageDown folks how they do this?  Also, **why** are you trying to render the markdown?  Shouldn't you store it on the server side-as is, then transmit it to the client?  I bet there's a standard way to render it in PageDown if you ask.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I figured PageDown was popular enough (it's what StackOverflow uses) that coming to StackOverflow was probably faster than trying to contact them directly. And I'm trying to convert the markdown to **sanitized** html on the client side. I am storing it on the server as-is. That part is done, now I'm trying to output it to clients for reading (not writing in an editor, just reading).

Comment: What does **"sanitized"** mean?

Comment: @markspace Sanitized means I'm passing it to the Markdown.getSanitizingConverter() instance, which simply removes any html tags not on the whitelist. It's more complicated than that though, as it does **not** strip html tags that are inside a code block, which is what I need. This makes it difficult to use a Java solution, as they all seem to be all-or-nothing instead of the selective sanitation that respects the code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for commenting when I don't know what's going on, but it seems no one else has had a go yet so here's an idea.

I found the [source to the sanitizer you mentioned](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Sanitizer.js), and it's just a regex of a white list of allowed tags.  Everything else is rejected, which seems pretty smart frankly.

```
// (tags that can be opened/closed) | (tags that stand alone)
var basic_tag_whitelist = /^(<\/?(b|blockquote|code|del|dd|dl|dt|em|h1|h2|h3|i|kbd|li|ol|p|pre|s|sup|sub|strong|strike|ul)>|<(br|hr)\s?\/?>)$/i;
// <a href="url..." optional title>|</a>
var a_white = /^(<a\shref="((https?|ftp):\/\/|\/)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+"(\stitle="[^"<>]+")?\s?>|<\/a>)$/i;

// <img src="url..." optional width  optional height  optional alt  optional title
var img_white = /^(<img\ssrc="(https?:\/\/|\/)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+"(\swidth="\d{1,3}")?(\sheight="\d{1,3}")?(\salt="[^"<>]*")?(\stitle="[^"<>]*")?\s?\/?>)$/i;
```

I don't think it would be too hard to translate these to Java regex.  Here's my go with the first regex string.

```
  Pattern white = Pattern.compile( "^(<\\/?(b|blockquote|code|del|dd|dl|dt|em|h1|h2|h3|i|kbd|li|ol|p|pre|s|sup|sub|strong|strike|ul)>|<(br|hr)\\s?\\/?>)$" );

  String test = "foo<p>bar";
  Matcher matcher = white.matcher(test);
  for(int i = 0;;) {
     int start = test.indexOf("<",i);
     if( start < 0 ) break;
     int end = test.indexOf( ">", start );
     if( end < 0 ) break;
     matcher.region(start, end+1);
     System.out.println(test.subSequence(start, end) );
     System.out.println( matcher.matches() );
     i = end;
  }
```

This prints "true" when it finds a white listed tag.  Otherwise you should mangle the first '<' to be a '& lt ;' (I can't type the HTML literal.  I think I found a bug in PageDown :-)) or whatever you prefer.

Whether you do this on the in-bound (post) path or on the out-bound (get) path is up to you, but the latter might be more flexible since it gives you the ability to adjust the white list to user privileges or changes to the white list later.

Good luck.

EDIT:

Wanted to add: you can run JavaScript from inside Java.  The Oracle JDK has the [Nashorn JavaScript engine built in](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html).  You'll probably have to do some work with binding so you can pass variables back and forth.

I don't know of the Open JDK comes with a JavaScript engine.  I don't think it does; it's still in progress.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. I was hoping for a more "standard" approach though, I've been assuming I'm just missing something obvious. I'm afraid this is an oversimplification though, as the PageDown sanitation doesn't touch html tags that are inside code blocks, whereas I think your code will remove them. That's why I was hoping for a standard solution instead of having to do the parsing myself.

Comment: Also, I can definitely call javascript from Java using the ScriptEngine class. I actually have this working fine, but it seems strange to do all the processing on the server. If that is indeed the way to go, I'll stop whining and just do it that way, haha.